# C: what does the notation x=y[a=b] imply?

Tags: c

I am trying to rewrite a piece of C code from another author into Python, and I came across the following type of notation:

```
x = y[a=b];
```

where `y` is an array and `a` and `b` are integers. At first I thought it meant something like this:

```
a = b;
x = y[a];
```

But apparently it doesn't. Can anyone tell me what this expression means? Forgive me if this question is a duplicate, but it is very hard to summarise this question in a couple of searchable keywords, and I could not find anything that answers my question.

The source of the code I am trying to rewrite: [link](http://www.gipsa-lab.grenoble-inp.fr/~laurent.condat/download/condat_fast_tv.c)

EDIT:

The Python-rewritten code does not work as it should (stuck in a loop), so I thought that I misinterpreted the above statement. But as several of you have suggested, it was correct in the first place. I must be something else then...

Comment: What is the line of code in your link?

Comment: You say C in the text and C++ in the title and tag. Which is it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this *is* just `a=b;x=y[a];`.

Comment: That is exactly what it means (modulo type conversion, aliasing, etc.). Why do you think that it doesn't?

Comment: Would recommend, for readability and sanity, not implementing it like that when you re-write it! :)

Comment: @NeilKirk the line in the original code is e.g. 89

Comment: can you tell us why do you doubt in meaning of this statement?

Comment: What makes you say "apparently it doesn't"? I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: `umax=(vmin=input[kminus=k=k0])+(umin=lambda)-vmax;` amazing

Comment: @NeilKirk would that expand to
    `umin=lambda;
    k=k0;
    kminus=k;
    vmin=input[kminus];
    umax = vmin + umin - vmax;`
?
I'm currently porting the same code!

Comment: @masher I believe so..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = y[a=b];
```

and

```
a = b;
x = y[a];
```

are equivalent.  The expression `a=b` has the value of the left operand after assignment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/474dd6e2.aspx

Comment: Don't you mean "the left hand operand", or "the left hand side of the operator"? `a` and `b` are the operands, `=` is the operator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference. Although my code still isn't working, at least I now know that the interpretation of `y[a=b]` was not the problem.

Comment: Let me just add, this actually comes up in C a *lot*, though not in the weird way that you are using it.

`while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` is idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are actually right, it means:

```
a = b;
x = y[a];
```

`a = b` itself returns `b` after assigning `b` to `a`. Therefore `y[a=b]` will return `y[b]` but also assigned `b` into `a`.

### EDIT

in your comment you say, "if a = 1 and b = 3, then it resolves to y[3] with a = 3 and b = 3".

This is exactly what the code above does:

At the beginning, `a` is equal to `1` and `b` is equal to `3`.

```
a = b;
```

Now `a` contains `3` and `b` still contains `3`.

```
x = y[a];
```

Now `x` has been assigned the value in `y[3]`, `a` still contains `3` and `b` still contains `3`.