# C: How does "if((a+=b) > c)" work?

Tags: c, refactoring, igor

I am trying to rewrite some C code from another author into Igor Pro (similarish notation to C).
The code is available [here](http://www.gipsa-lab.grenoble-inp.fr/~laurent.condat/download/condat_fast_tv.c).

I don't know how to deal with the lines `if ((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)<minlambda)` and `else if ((umax+=input[k+1]-vmax)>lambda)` with regards to the order of how they go about updating `umin` and `umax`, and how the if/elseif statements evaluating to true or false affect the update..

Specifically:

On lines 99-107 there is:

```
        if ((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)<minlambda) {        
            do output[k0++]=vmin; while (k0<=kminus);
            vmax=(vmin=input[kplus=kminus=k=k0])+twolambda;
            umin=lambda; umax=minlambda;
        } else if ((umax+=input[k+1]-vmax)>lambda) {    
            do output[k0++]=vmax; while (k0<=kplus);
            vmin=(vmax=input[kplus=kminus=k=k0])-twolambda;
            umin=lambda; umax=minlambda;
        } else { /*blah blah */ }
```

I have refactored this to read:

```
    if ((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin) < minlambda) //Todo
        do
            output[k0] = vmin
            k0+=1
        while(k0 <= kminus)

        k=k0
        kminus=k
        kplus=kminus
        vmin=input[kplus]
        vmax = (vmin) + twolambda
        umin = lambda
        umax = minlambda

    elseif ((umax+=input[k+1]-vmax) > lambda) //Todo
        do
            output[k0]=vmax
            k0+=1
        while(k0 <= kplus)

        k=k0
        kminus=k
        kplus=kminus
        vmax=input[kplus]
        vmin = (vmax) - twolambda
        umin = lambda
        umax = minlambda        
    else //blah blah
```

Do umin and umax only get updated if their if statements evaluate to true? Or does it cascade? IF(umin) -> false, umin updated, ELSEIF(umax) -> true, umax updated, but IF(umin) -> true, umin updated, umax not updated? Or some other variant?

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310683/c-what-does-the-notation-x-ya-b-imply) about the same code.

Edit: fixed title. Added igor tag

Comment: Note that the expression isn't `a += b > c`, it's `(a += b) > c`, quite a different thing.

Comment: @joachim I fixed the title.

Comment: in C and many C-like languages, [assignment operators return the value that is assigned to the variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3807192/995714). [What is the benefit of having the assignment operator return a value?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/228851/98103)

Comment: This is no valid C. Semicolons missing, no braces, C does not have `elseif`. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @olaf what isn't valid C? The first lot of code is a straight copy/paste.  The second lot of code is in Igor as explained in my first paragraph.

Comment: That's a terrible codding , please don't code like that.

Comment: @Michi it's not the OPs fault. The original code is downright disgusting and he's trying to recode it in another language

Comment: @michi what is terrible? The C code or the Igor code?

Comment: It was just a suggestion to never write a code like that.

Comment: @masher: "similar to C" would be C++, or Java. This is far from "similar. Anyway: did I remove the C tag? Not yet! You are apparently asking about the behaviour of a **different** language and only use the C code as a starting point, So the C tag is irrelevant and you should add a tag for the target language.

Comment: @olaf I am asking about the behaviour of the C code and how the if statements expand. I've already got one response that looks like it is written in VBA, but it is easy enough to understand.

Comment: @masher Hard to say, because you said that you try to recode it. My question is why do someone try to recode something if he doesn't understand **if((a+=b) > c)**. This sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for (;;) {
....
  if ((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)<minlambda) {        
        do output[k0++]=vmin; while (k0<=kminus);
        vmax=(vmin=input[kplus=kminus=k=k0])+twolambda;
        umin=lambda; umax=minlambda;
    } else if ((umax+=input[k+1]-vmax)>lambda) {    
        do output[k0++]=vmax; while (k0<=kplus);
        vmin=(vmax=input[kplus=kminus=k=k0])-twolambda;
        umin=lambda; umax=minlambda;
    } else { /*blah blah */ }
}
```

(from the original source) is more or less equivalent to this

```
for (;;)
{
    ...
    umin += input[k + 1] - vmin;
    if (umin < minlambda) 
    {
        ...
        continue;
    }
    umax += input[k + 1] - vmax;
    if (umax > lambda)
    {
         ....
        continue;
    }
    /* blah blah */
}
```

You can do this because the if block is at the end of a loop, otherwise you'd need some `else`'s and extra indenting which would be moderately less pretty (but probably still easier to understand).

Comment: OK. I might want to put a second conditional on the second if statement to ensure that the first evaluated to false. But I do get your reasoning.

Comment: @masher you don't need to because of the continue at the end of the previous if block

Answer (score 3):

```
if( a += b > c)
```

In this first `b>c` is evaluated as `>` has higher precedence than `+=` .

Then  `+=` will be evaluated. 
 Now , if `b>c` is true then  `a` will be `a+=1` and if it is false then `a+=0` will be evaluated .

Now this (*as you updated your title*)-

```
 if ((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)<minlambda)
```

In this first `(umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)` will be evaluated .Why ? due to brackets `()` having higher precedence than `<`.

In `(umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)`  , due to precedence of `-` is higher than `+=`. `input[k+1]-vmin` is evaluated and then its result is added to `umin` and stored in `umin`.

After this evaluation it is compared with `minlamda`.

Similarly you can understand how this will work (*ofcourse if condition in `if` is `false`*) -

```
else if ((umax+=input[k+1]-vmax)>lambda)
```

here also `umax` will be updated and then it will be compared with `lambda`.

Comment: It is `if((a+=b) > c)`

Comment: Thanks.  So the `elseif` statement is only evaluated when the `if` statement is false, by which time umin has already been updated.

Comment: @masher There is no **elseif** in C, please get a Book.

Comment: Terribly sorry Michi. I forgot a space while I was typing on my phone. Here is one for you  .

Answer (score 1):

`umin` will be updated every time you enter there.
`umax` will be updated by `(umax+=input[k+1]-vmax) > lambda` if and only if `(umin+=input[k+1]-vmin) < minlambda` is false because it is in `else if`

`a+=b > c` works as `if(b>c)a+=1; else a+=0;`

`(a+=b)>c` works as `(a+=b),a>c`, which returns `a>c` after adding `b` to `a`.

Comment: OK, so it is a cascading thing. I'll have to have a think about how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it this way:

```
((umin+=input[k+1]-vmin)<minlambda)
```

is essentially

```
var umin += input[k+1] - vmin;
if (umin < minlambda) { }
else if ((umax += input[k+1] - vmax)> lambda) { }
```

`umin` is just calculated inside the if statement and then compared to `minlambda`

Comment: So does that mean that umin is updated on every iteration and umax is only updated when if(umin) evaluates to false?

Comment: Yes, exactly, else it would enter the if and skip the `else if umax` section.

Comment: In your example, umin and umax are updated regardless of the truthness of either if statement. I thought that the update cascaded, and umax was updated iff umin evaluated to false.

Comment: I'm currently on the train, and such thinking is beyond me!@!